# Class 'ProductRepository' must implement 'Sub Remove(Id As Integer)' for interface 'IProductRepository'

Tags: .net, vb.net

I was trying to convert the C# code in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations to VB .Net.

I have created interface IProductRepository like below,

```
Namespace ProductStore.Models

    Interface IProductRepository

        Function GetAll() As IEnumerable(Of Product)

        Function [Get](ByVal id As Integer) As Product

        Function Add(ByVal item As Product) As Product

        Sub Remove(ByVal id As Integer)

        Function Update(ByVal item As Product) As Boolean

    End Interface
End Namespace
```

Then created ProductRepository class as below,

```
Namespace ProductStore.Models

    Public Class ProductRepository
        Inherits IProductRepository

        Private products As List(Of Product) = New List(Of Product)()

        Private _nextId As Integer = 1

        Public Sub New()
            Add(New Product With {.Name = "Tomato soup", .Category = "Groceries", .Price = 1.39D})
            Add(New Product With {.Name = "Yo-yo", .Category = "Toys", .Price = 3.75D})
            Add(New Product With {.Name = "Hammer", .Category = "Hardware", .Price = 16.99D})
        End Sub

        Public Function GetAll() As IEnumerable(Of Product)
            Return products
        End Function

        Public Function [Get](ByVal id As Integer) As Product
            Return products.Find(Function(p) p.Id = id)
        End Function

        Public Function Add(ByVal item As Product) As Product
            If item Is Nothing Then
                Throw New ArgumentNullException("item")
            End If

            item.Id = Math.Min(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(_nextId), _nextId - 1)
            products.Add(item)
            Return item
        End Function

        Public Sub Remove(ByVal id As Integer)
            products.RemoveAll(Function(p) p.Id = id)
        End Sub

        Public Function Update(ByVal item As Product) As Boolean
            If item Is Nothing Then
                Throw New ArgumentNullException("item")
            End If

            Dim index As Integer = products.FindIndex(Function(p) p.Id = item.Id)
            If index = -1 Then
                Return False
            End If

            products.RemoveAt(index)
            products.Add(item)
            Return True
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

But i am getting error for the line Inherits IProductRepository as "Classes can inherit only from other classes.". When I changed Inherits to Implements like below
 Implements IProductRepository

I am getting following errors,

> Class 'ProductRepository' must implement 'Function GetAll() As
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Product)' for interface
>   'IProductRepository'

and same for other interfaces in IProductRepository. Could you please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class **ProductRepository** should implement the interface **IProductRepository** like,

```
Public Class ProductRepository
        Implements IProductRepository
```

and you must explicitly use the **Implements** keyword to implement the interface methods in the ProductRepository class

```
Public Function GetAll() As IEnumerable(Of Product) Implements IProductRepository.GetAll
            Return products
End Function
```

Comment: *and* they do need to carry out the swap for `Inherits` to `Implements` at the top, which they indicated that they've tried. If they take just the original code in the question and add `Implements` to the methods, they'll still have an error.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, ok. Just to avoid confusion, I have added that the class declaration too.